# How do I select a specific property in nested array json rails 5

Tags: multidimensional-array, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-hash

I need help with this. I would like to access transactionCustomFields and I would like to get the token from the response.

```
  {
   "event":"TRANSACTION OUTCOME",
  "timestamp":1672749136029,

  "data":{
  "transactionId":"b5247b19-1e14-4f3e-818f-a3b1554dd64b",
  "transactionStatus":"SUCCESS",
  "statusDescription":"SUCCESS",
  "transaction":{
     "id":"b5247b19-1e14-4f3e-818f-a3b1554dd64b",
     "paymentMethod":"MOBILE_MONEY",
     "transactionType":"PULL",
     "phoneNumber":"+256754187853",
     "telecom":"AIRTEL",
     "amount":500,
     "status":"SUCCESS",
     "narration":"",
     "failedDescription":null,
     "webhookUrl":"https://webhook.site/cbf423c2-15f5-46f3-9c76-1dcc0b9a2e18",
     "createdAt":"2023-01-03T12:32:04.176Z",
     "transactionCustomFields":[
        {
           "id":"1fc25a5c-ba0b-4959-b295-31628d8da0e1",
           "key":"token",
           "value":"31644"
        },
        {
           "id":"2686effb-4f40-45ac-867f-b39d84282dae",
           "key":"reference",
           "value":"1672749122"
        }
     ]
  }}}
```

This is the JSON response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to access the first item of the "transactionCustomFields" array and its id/key you could do something like this.

```
json_object = JSON.parse(response)

json_object['data']['transaction']["transactionCustomFields"][0]["key"] //gives you token
json_object['data']['transaction']["transactionCustomFields"][0]["id"] //gives you "1fc25a5c-ba0b-4959-b295-31628d8da0e1"
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: This works like Charm and what if i want to get transaction then get amount and other values like phoneNumber Do i follow the above?

Comment: Yes, it would work for any key present in your response json. I suggest you use a tool like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to format your data in a more readable way. Then you can just replace the above code with your desired keys

Comment: Thanks for the help. In fact it worked well. I followed the above formart and all worked